# VLookup in 'Do While' loop

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

This 'Do While' loop executes, however the vlookup has a small error. When the vlookup result is "NA" the previously stored value for vLook is input to the destination (cells(z,20)). I basically want to say iferror(vlookup(...),"") so that the new stored value is zero then update vLook value to "" and input in the new active cell.

```
Sub test3()

Dim text1 As String, text2 As String, text3 As String
Dim vLook As Variant
Dim lookupRange As Range

Set lookupRange = Sheet3.Range("x5:y500")

Z = 5

Do While Sheet3.Cells(Z, 1) <> ""

On Error Resume Next

text1 = Sheet3.Cells(Z, 23)

vLook = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(text1, lookupRange, 2, False)
Sheet3.Cells(Z, 20).Activate
ActiveCell.Formula = vLook


Z = Z + 1
Sheet3.Cells(Z, 24).Select

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the `WorksheetFunction` then the lookup will not raise an error if no match is found: instead you can test the return value using `IsError()`

```
Sub test3()

    Dim text1 As String
    Dim vLook As Variant
    Dim lookupRange As Range

    Set lookupRange = Sheet3.Range("x5:y500")

    Z = 5

    Do While Sheet3.Cells(Z, 1) <> ""
        text1 = Sheet3.Cells(Z, 23).Value
        vLook = Application.VLookup(text1, lookupRange, 2, False)
        Sheet3.Cells(Z, 20).Value = IIf(IsError(vLook), "N/A", vLook)
        Z = Z + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I didn't know the IIF function existed. Thanks a ton.